# htaccess - redirect based on the request origin

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, 301-redirect

Please help me out here. I would like to use .htaccess to redirect based on request origin, for example:

User requests:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

And should be redirected to:

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

This is very simple to accomplish BUT on the homepage there is a link to:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

And it should work **just WHEN** the request comes from that link.

In other words my goal is to force all users through the homepage **BEFORE**  other URLs even if they know the page URL (bookmarked or otherwise) and it is a valid one.

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't do this in a .htaccess, do it in teh server config.

Comment: Iain, change the server config it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but there's no guarantee of 100% success rate.  The easiest would be by using the ${HTTP_REFERER} header.  The problem is, users can turn this off in their browsers and some bots don't send it.  This is more suited for the application logic using sessions.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.domain\.com/?$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

In the second line, the $ is the important part.  It will only match if there is nothing after the .com or .com/
The third line is just a standard match for the root request_uri.  Please note both conditions have the ! operator, which means if the referrer does **not** match http://www.domain.com/

Try this out and let me know.

Comment: thank you for stopping by and give me something to research, maybe a way out. Unfortunately it didn't work, nothing happened.
I was thinking, perhaps we have to change the approach, do you think it is possible to deny access to the URL for all and allow just when the request comes from www.domain.com? Something using that order deny,allow thing?